# Inlining a Public Variable in a User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control with a variable that I am trying to display inline in the Aspx page, but it always shows as empty. I've done this in other user controls and I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Aspx...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyClass.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyClass" %>

<%# sMyPublicString %>
```

Code Behind...

```
public partial class MYClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string sMyPublicString = "MyValue";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In parent webform on `Page_Load` you have to add `Page.DataBind()`

Comment: Page.DataBind() caused a few problems but this.DataBind() worked like a charm!